# How to hold a watch for product photography?

Tags: product-photography

As commented, I'm doing some product photography for smartwatches, I want to achieve certain "poses" with the watch...

[image: smartWatch]

I have tried different options like plasticine but, the shape and angle of the resulting images are not as good as the sample image.

So I need to find a way that I can photograph different watches with the same reproducible angle on my lightbox...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hang them.

1. Use some wood sticks tied with some cotton treads hardened with glue.
2. Use a metal hanger unwrapped.
3. Use a PVC rig and hang the watches using "invisible" nylon thread hooked with unwrapped paper clips. I like this one the better. It is the least intrusive on the shot, it can become too bulky, but you can cut different rigs for different projects.

[image]

PVC is the DIY photographer's best friend. I do not know the exact diameter, but the one I use a lot is around 2.1cm or 3/4 inch. The caps are important because they stabilize it.

[image]

Be imaginative and have fun to construct new rigs for each project.

You can still need to use some paper clips to keep some straps with a correct shape.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To hold the watch what fundamental use is a plastic box truly basic. I have several wires here simply electrical wire however we utilize these to fold the watch over now in competitive position is and hold it in position and furthermore, in case you will on shop use it to give it an appearance as though a lash is open and helping me simply get out the wires that are left in photoshop

[image]

Comment: great reference thank you!